# Dependency Injection where to use "new" Operator

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm "new" at using Dependency Injection and my question is: where can I use the `new` Operator? In the following I will show you an example, and I like to know if I use the `new` operator correctly.

The Example is for ASP.NET MVC with a `CustomControllerFactory`, everything works fine so far.

First I have My Entity Class `Member`:

```
public partial class Member
{
    public Member()
    {
        this.LoginTries = 0;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public int LoginTries { get; set; }
}
```

Then there is a interface for some user actions:

```
public interface IDiMembership<TUser>
{
    bool Login(string username, string password, bool rememberMe = false);
    void Logout();
    //This is the Function I am using later and where i am using the new Operator
    bool CreateUser(string username, string password, TUser user);
    ...
}
```

My implementation for my interface:

```
public class DiMembership : IDiMembership<Member>
{
    ...
    public bool CreateUser(string username, string password, Member user)
    {
        user.PasswordSalt = Crypto.GenerateSalt();
        user.Password = Crypto.HashPassword(
            string.Format("{0}{1}", password, user.PasswordSalt));
        user.Username = username;
        user.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
        ...
     }
```

And my `Controller` call, and here is also my question is: it right to call the `CreateUser` method with a new "Member" or to create a new `Member` Object an prefill some values? Is this DI conform or how to solve the problem right?

```
private readonly IDiMembership<Member> _membership;
public AccountController(IDiMembership<Member> membership)
{
        _membership = membership;
}

public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && 
        _membership.CreateUser(model.Username, model.Password, new Member()))
    {
       return RedirectToAction("RegisterSuccess");
    }
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Read this: [To "new" or not to "new"](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice following approach:

- complex objects (the ones requiring some business logic or complex process to initialize properly) should be created via factories
- simple enough objects (eg. [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) or [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object)) can be created anywhere

If your `RegisterModel` is only storing several simple values, there's no point to delegate its creation to factory as it's too much stretch and unnecessary classes creation.

Do you use a factory for `string`, `int` or `DateTime`? No. But as soon as those simple values get promoted to some higher level of complexity or have some business logic attached we switch from *newing* them to dedicated objects for creation - think about `StringBuilder` or `Random`.

Answer (score 1):

Some DI frameworks provide factories for this purpose, so you won't ever need to call the `new` operator. For example, Castle Windsor provides [Typed factories](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx).

With this, you'd just define the interface:

```
public interface IUserFactory
{
  public IUser CreateUser(string username, string password...);
}
```

And register that interface as a factory. Windsor will provide the implementation for this interface, which will match the following constructor on the following class (assuming you registered User as a component):

```
public class User : IUser
{
  public User(string username, string password ...)
  {

  }

}
```

Logically, your controller would also have to declare this factory as a dependency.

```
public class AccountController
{
  private IUserFactory _userFactory;

  public AccountController(IUserFactory userFactory)
  {
    _userFactory = userFactory;
  }

  public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
  {
    IUser user = _userFactory.CreateUser(model.Username, model.Password);
    ...
  }
}
```

If, however, you're not using any framework, or your framework doesn't provide factory implementations, then you could write your own factories, which hold a reference to your components container and are able to resolve IUser when you call their `Create` methods.

This way, you won't need to call the `new` operator to instantiate new objects as part of your controller's logic.

Comment: I've always liked this pattern.  It isolates the construction of dynamic objects to a single location in your application.  With factories to create even the simplest of objects, you can endow your objects with a greater set of responsibilities, decrease uses of getters/setters, and make a class' actual dependencies clearer  I wonder, do you know anyone who has created an application with NO new operators (besides composition root)?  I have always wanted to try, but the extra infrastructure (at least double the amount of classes) makes it impractical to implement, I find at least.

Comment: @jrahhali, I'm now discovering the DI pattern, and look over entire web, looking for answer to the question that you put:how to create factories - classes whose responsibility is to create other objects based on some runtime calculations — and not to break the DI principle: not to use the “new” operator nor invoke the DI controller directly.
It seems to me that the correct answer is:

Comment: the one you suggested: create factories even for the simplest objects. 

BTW, in PHP (in which i write) allows to create anonimous classes, like closures:
$myFactory = new class($container) { //class definition goes here }
this allows not to double the number of classes